# Disable automatic text copy on select in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, copy

I was wondering how to disable the automatic copy of text when it is selected with the mouse in Lubuntu.

I've looked through the very little posts on the topic that I could find, but most of them were about Gnome and Unity.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about - first I select the text I need pasted somewhere else and press Ctrl+C to copy it (old habits from Windows), then I go to the browser or text editor and select the part I need replaced and when I press Ctrl+V to paste the previously copied text it pastes the text I've just selected with the mouse... so I have to delete the selection, go back to the other text, copy it again and then paste it...

In other words I'm looking for a way to make it behave like Windows - the text should be copied in the clipboard only through Ctrl+C or a context menu.

This is a nice feature for the terminal (and I wouldn't mind if it can be kept just there) but everywhere else it just slows down my work a lot. Also learning to work in another way (like deleting the text first and then copy-paste) is not an option because I'm forced to work also on Windows and Mac where this behavior doesn't exist so it will just be too confusing.

Comment: Sounds like you have something syncing the primary and clipboard buffers. Maybe try http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119048/70524?

Comment: @muru - There is no clipman installed with Lubuntu so at least in theory that wasn't the problem. I installed it and the problem was fixed so if you make this as an answer I'll accept it, though I'm still curious if there is a way to solve the problem by using only the apps that come with the standard Lubuntu without having to install any additional software.

Comment: It might not be Clipman itself. It could be some other utility that set both buffers to be synced. That should be investigated, I suppose, since I strongly doubt Lubuntu would make something like this the default.

Comment: @muru - Guess you might be right - I've just tested it on a freshly installed VM with Lubuntu and everything works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is getting too weird - I turned off Clipman and things didn't break... I also rebooted the machine and everything kept working fine even though Clipman wasn't loaded at all. Unless this buffer syncing is set inside a config file that's used by other apps and/or the OS itself  I'd say that there is something very wrong with my installation. //EDIT: Just removed clipman with the purge option of apt and everything still works fine even after I rebooted.